# How do I move left or up?

Tags: pc, oddworld-munchs-odyssey

On the menu it says that to navigate, you have to use the arrow keys, but only the right and down arrow keys actually do anything.

This makes it very hard do perform certain tasks (such as saving) as the cursor will appear on the bottom right on the pause menu.

Does it mean that there are other keyboard controls that I'm missing or have I managed to change these buttons without realising?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you can access the control settings in the main menu, and disable the gamepad controls.

Comment: Oddly enough, that worked.